# GoogleTest initialization by reference

Tags: c++, googletest

What is the reason, why GoogleTest uses reference for the parameter count?

```
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
```

(I mean: as I understand, this is an input parameter and makes no difference
whether a value or an address is provided)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [comments](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/7f4448f40b3f3f16a75787c016139511579367ed/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h#L1354).

> ```
> // Initializes Google Test.  This must be called before calling
> // RUN_ALL_TESTS().  In particular, it parses a command line for the
> // flags that Google Test recognizes.  Whenever a Google Test flag is
> // seen, it is removed from argv, and *argc is decremented.
> ```